# Can I document.write from a url?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wanting to have a message on every page that I can change with ease. I'm very new to JS but have worked with HTML and CSS for over 3 years now.

This is what I've got so far.

```
<script>document.write(url="/message.html");
```

The purpose of this is almost like an iFrame. I want a message on every page that I can change with ease. I want to use JS because it is only one line of code I want to print.

```
<p>NEW!!! - GO CLICK <a href="#">HERE</a> FOR DETAILS</p>
```

It would be very annoying and difficult to change this single line of code on 30 or so different pages. I would like to have a single file (message.html) and have that displayed.

[More info...](http://www.tropilac.com/test/index.html)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use an iframe?

Comment: I have  in the past but there is only one line of text that I want to display. I do not want excess CSS.@Paulpro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I can create a single line of script code that will run a .js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="message.js"></script>
```

'message.js'

```
document.write("<p>This is my message.</p>");
```

Works well and does exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you to all who helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
// using jQuery to load a template to id result
$( "#result" ).load( "/templates/message.html" );
```

More info here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Not sure what you are using . I will just assume you're using jQuery at least. IF you use a framework they all have templating solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain what jQuery is or if i have it? As I said, totally new.

Comment: I have copied and pasted what you have said above and nothing is displayed on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a string as a hyperlink.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Testing!";
    var result = str.link("http://www.google.com");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this. Refer the below code. Add your public contents to the page.html

```html
<script>$("#test1").load("http://example/page.html");</script>
<div id="test1"></div>
```

Comment: Does JQuery require to be on a server. Can I run this of a hard drive or must it be on a web server to work? As I said, new to JS.

Comment: Yes. you can run it on your hard drive. Just try it :-)